# Using both Laravel blade and vue variables together

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I am trying to use both vue and blade variables to make calculation as follow :

```
@{{vueNumber}} * {{$bladeNumber}}
```

and I would want to get result of multiplying these 2 numbers.

I have tried using vue variable inside @php and it threw error , how can this be achievable ?

Comment: That's not going to work. You'll need to either pass the Vue variable to Laravel, or the Laravel variable to Vue.

Comment: use components & pass the view variable to vuejs via props